# Trying to parse this with simplexml (php)

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en">MerchantException</faultstring>
    <detail>store id is missing</detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have tried the following code to get the 'detail' tag, but keeps coming up with blanks:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$posts = $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Fault;
foreach ($posts as $post)
  {
    echo $post->detail;  
}
```

Appreciate assistance

Answer (score 1):

When using `children()`, you sort of change the namespace that SimpleXML is working in.  As `<detail>` is in the default namespace, you need to (again) change the namespace it's using to the default one by using `children()` with no namespace defined...

```
echo $post->children()->detail;
```

The test code is...

```
$result = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">MerchantException</faultstring>
            <detail>store id is missing</detail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$posts = $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Fault;
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    echo $post->children()->detail;
}
```

which shows...

```
store id is missing
```

Comment: That is still coming up blank

Comment: I've added my test code to the question which shows the answer.  Can you check that `$result` is the same as you show in the question.

Comment: Got it, I had another loop wrapped around it - echo $post->children()->detail; worked, thank you so much - I think you saved me from a heart attack this morning - been bashing my head why this wouldnt work!